# How do I draw my particles when an enemy is killed?

Tags: python, pygame

I have enemies that move left and right.
I was wonder how I could make my particles show up when the enemy is killed?

Here is my particle class

```
    class explode:
        
        def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            self.explode = [
            pygame.image.load("spark_01.png"),
            pygame.image.load("spark_02.png"),
            pygame.image.load("spark_03.png"),
            pygame.image.load("spark_04.png"),
            pygame.image.load("spark_05.png"),
            pygame.image.load("spark_06.png"),
            pygame.image.load("spark_07.png")]

            self.explode = [pygame.transform.scale(image,(image.get_width()//7,image.get_height()//7)) for image in self.explode]

            self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
            self.direction = "blobright"
            self.anim_index = 0
        def draw(self):
             
            self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
            if self.direction == "blobright":
                window.blit(self.explode[self.anim_index], self.rect)
                self.anim_index += 1
                if self.anim_index == len(self.explode):
                    self.anim_index = 0
            



    black = (0,0,0)
    explode1 = explode(400,450,50,50,black)
    explodes = [explode1]
```

This is where I delete my enemies when they are killed. How can I add my particles after it's deleted and remove the particles afterward?

```
        #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- enemys

                # enemys 2
            for enemys in enemying:
                for bullet in bullets:
                    if bullet.rect.colliderect(enemys.hitbox):
                        if enemys.health > -4:
                            enemys.health -= 1
                            minusenemyhealthtext()
                            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                        else:
                            enemyscore += 1
                            del enemying[one]
                            enemyors = font.render("" + str(enemyscore), True, (0,0,0))
                            enemydors.center = ((130,125))
```

Answer (score 0):

What I've done is add a delete method to the Enemy class, in this method you will create the explosion using the enemy's position, and call it just before deleting the enemy.